# Web-API Swagger/Swashbuckle - Link field to database lookup list

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

What is the best way, using Swashbuckle, to identify that the value for a particular field should be a string from a database lookup list?

What I think I'm looking for, is some way to decorate a model property, to indicate that it's an enumeration, but without actually declaring the type as an enum?

The list of valid values might only contain 5 to 10 items. However they can't be defined as an actual enum in my application as they're editable through a CMS, and stored in a database table.

At the moment I've just defined these properties as strings, and then provided some documentation to indicate which endpoint can be used to retrieve the list of valid values.

This doesn't seem like a very correct way to do it. I would really like to lock it down a bit better, so there's no room for confusion for a developer trying to use the api.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @Edgaras No, I didn't find a nice way to do this, so just provided additional documentation to explain where to get the allowed values. It's not an api with a large audience, so hasn't really been a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something like that with the `pattern` validation keyword:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.2.3

Your swagger.json will look like:

```
"Transparency": {
  "type": "string",
  "pattern": "^(high|medium|low)"
},
```

For that you have two options:

- On your C# code you need to have

`[RegularExpression("^(high|medium|low)")]`
`public string Transparency { get; set; }`

- Or add the pattern at runtime using an iDocumentFilter

Comment: Thanks. This will certainly help for some of the properties.